# Has the TrackMania Speed-Up! ever have been released?

Tags: trackmania-series

[The wiki](http://en.tm-wiki.org/wiki/TrackMania_Original) claims that TrackMania Speed-Up! was published in March 2004, while [this gamerkings post](http://www.gamerankings.com/pc/960497-trackmania-original/index.html) says that the Speed Up! patches were never released. Who is right?

Comment: Those are two completely separate things you mention. One is "Trackmania Power-Up", yet the other are "Speed Up! *patches*".  An add-on is completely different from a patch (content vs fix).

Comment: @memescientist Sorry I meant Speed-Up! only. I fixed the typo.

Comment: I know I have the box copy of something like that probably power up. It was in a black case.